# Python/Selenium Locating element

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i make my script to find this button:

```
https://gyazo.com/def9d478c923306673da8186187f25c6
```

It has:

```
class="button"
type="submit"
accesskey="s"
title="Enter your username and password in the boxes provided to login, or        click the 'register' button to create
value = "log in"
```

I've researched the locating options but couldn't find the option i need so I think xpath should be the right option but I couldn't manage to find it in xpath.

Comment: Try to solve your question first- then, if you fail post here. I see you have more that one question answered by you after a little while question is posted!

Answer (score 1):

Given what you've provided, how about we rely on the `value` attribute:

```
//input[@value = 'Log in']
```

Answer (score 0):

so i solved the problem by using the literal xpath

```
x =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")
```